# Family of linear one-step method, $A$-stable

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the family of linear one-step methods defined by $$y_n = y_{n-1} + h(\theta f_n + (1 - \theta)f_{n-1})$$ where $0\leq \theta \leq 1$.

Relevant definition- A difference method is $A$-stable if its region of absolute stability contains the entire left half-plane of $z = h\lambda$.

Show that the methods associated with $0\leq \theta < 1/2$ cannot be $A$-stable.

Using the advice from user LutzL we have:

Let $$f_k = \lambda y_k$$
then $$y_n(1 - \theta\lambda h) = y_{n-1}(1 + (1 - \theta)\lambda h)$$ sorting the inequality $$2Re(z) < (2\theta - 1)|z|^2$$ which requires $(2\theta - 1)\geq 0$ to get the condition for $A$-stability, hence the methods associated with $0\leq \theta < 1/2$ cannot be $A$-stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert
$$
f_k=λy_k
$$
to get
$$
y_n·(1-θλh)=y_{n−1}·(1+(1−θ)λh)
$$
and thus the stability condition
$$
\left|\frac{1+(1−θ)z}{1-θz}\right|<1.
$$

Comment: So this shows that the methods cannot be $A$-stable? I can't understand why I do not see it

Comment: You'd have to solve it to get a  condition on $z$, first is using the squared equation $1+2(1−θ)·Re(z)+(1−θ)^2·|z|^2<1-2θ·Re(z)+θ^2·|z|^2$.

Comment: I assume this solution is also ugly?

Comment: So once we insert $f_k = \lambda y_k$ to get etc... then we use the squared equation? I am not sure if I completely understanding this still.

Comment: No, this is a simple straightforward calculation. The next and final step is to sort the inequality out to get $2Re(z)<(2θ-1)|z|^2$ which requires $2θ-1\ge0$ to get the condition for A-stability.

Comment: Ok, so starting from the stability condition you present, we sort the inequality out to get $2Re(z) < (2\theta - 1)|z|^2$?

Comment: I edited the answer using what you did, let me know if it is correct or if I need more information to explain the steps. Thanks!

Comment: For here you do not need more steps, in you exam that might be different. Note that for $θ\in[0,\frac12)$ the stability region is a circle in the negative halp-plane tangent to the imaginary axis. (And for the other values of $θ$ the complement is a circle in the positive half-plane.)